# Bootstrap treeview Select children on root click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, treeview, bootstrap-treeview

i am using Bootstrap Treeview (bootstrap-treeview.js v1.0.2);
how can i activate selection effect on all chidren of root node on click of root?

This snippet doesn't work as expected

```
$('#tree')
    .on('nodeSelected', function (event, node) {
        children=node['nodes'];
        for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            children[i].states.expanded = true;
            children[i].states.selected = true;
        }
});
```

and this works only on the first child

```
$('#tree')
    .on('nodeSelected', function (event, node) {
        children=node['nodes'];
        for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            nodeId=children[i]['nodeId'];
            console.log(nodeId);
            $('.node-tree[data-nodeid="'+nodeId+'"]').click();
        }
});
```

Comment: You forgot to `var` your `children` and `nodeId` variables. This is a bug. Never forget to use `var`.

Comment: Sure, that's a mistake, but  'children[i].states.selected = true' related on click event doesn't make any change on children nodes... seems not work as expected.

Comment: I don't know very much about bootstrap treeview. A quick search turned up this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21878141/18771 - maybe it helps.

Answer (score 7):

Refer to my code below,
note that you need make sure your data option "multiSelect" is true.

```
var tree = $('#caseview').treeview({
    levels: 2,
    showTags: true,
    showCheckbox: true,
    multiSelect: true,
    data: caseData
});

caseview.on('nodeSelected', function(e, node){
    if (typeof node['nodes'] != "undefined") {
        var children = node['nodes'];
        for (var i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
            caseview.treeview('selectNode', [children[i].nodeId, { silent: true } ]);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: How do I select `children of children` or `children of children of children`, ect' ?

Answer (score 3):

I adapted the function "_getChildren" from [feiyuw](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34649058/704830):

```
function _getChildren(node) {
    if (node.nodes === undefined) return [];
    var childrenNodes = node.nodes;
    node.nodes.forEach(function(n) {
        childrenNodes = childrenNodes.concat(_getChildren(n));
    });
    return childrenNodes;
}

var tree = $('#tree').treeview({
    level: 3,
    expandIcon: "fa fa-plus-square",
    collapseIcon: "fa fa-minus-square",
    emptyIcon: "fa fa-truck",
    showTags: true,
    showCheckbox: true,
    selectable: false,
    highlightSelected: false,
    data: getTree()
}).on('nodeChecked', function (event, node){
    var childrenNodes = _getChildren(node);
    $(childrenNodes).each(function(){
        $(trucks).treeview('checkNode', [ this.nodeId, { silent: true } ]);;
    });
}).on('nodeUnchecked', function (event, node){
    var childrenNodes = _getChildren(node);
    $(childrenNodes).each(function(){
        $(trucks).treeview('uncheckNode', [ this.nodeId, { silent: true } ]);;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I also meet this problem, below is my solution (NOTE: I use lodash here):

```
function _getChildren(node) {
  if (node.nodes === undefined) return [];
  var childrenNodes = node.nodes;
  node.nodes.forEach(function(n) {
    childrenNodes = childrenNodes.concat(_getChildren(n));
  });

  return childrenNodes;
}

$('#tree').treeview({
  data: data,
  levels: 1,
  showCheckbox: true,
  showBorder: false,
  showTags: false,
  selectable: false,
  multiSelect: true,
  highlightSelected: false,
  onNodeChecked: function(event, node) {
    var parentNodes = _getParents([node], $(this));
    var childrenNodes = _.map(_getChildren(node), 'nodeId');
    var allNodes = parentNodes.concat(childrenNodes);
    $(this).treeview('checkNode', [allNodes, {silent: true}]);
  },
});
```

Comment: Where is the "_getParents" function?

Comment: oh, sorry, forgot to paste it.

Answer (score 0):

just make *select = true*

```
var tree = $('#caseview').treeview({
    selectable: true, // enable here, if exist, otherwise append it line
    data: caseData
})
.on('nodeSelected', function(e, node){
    if (node['text'].includes(".doc") { // text as name of node
        doit()
    }
})
```

> ".doc" - is example of file extension to select files instead folders
>
> doit() - is your code to continue

Answer (score 0):

Hope that helps you

```
$('#tree').on('click', (event) => {
  handleEventClick(event.target, false);
});

function handleEventClick(target) {
  if ($(target) && $(target).attr('data-nodeid')) {
    const nodeIdSelected = +$(target).attr('data-nodeid');
    const currentNode = $('#tree').treeview('getNode', nodeIdSelected);
    if (currentNode) {
      const isSelected = currentNode.state.selected;
      const listNodeChild = getNodeChildByNodeInfo(currentNode);
      if (listNodeChild.length) {
        listNodeChild.forEach(nodeChild => {
          $('#tree').treeview('expanded', nodeChild.nodeId);
          $('#tree').treeview(isSelected ? 'selectNode' : 'unselectNode', nodeChild.nodeId);
        });
      }
      toggleNodeSelectedParent(currentNode);
    }
  }
}

function getNodeChildByNodeInfo(currentNode) {
  let listNodeChild = [];
  if (currentNode.nodes && currentNode.nodes.length) {
    currentNode.nodes.forEach(item => {
      listNodeChild.push(item);
      if (item.nodes && item.nodes.length) {
        listNodeChild = [...listNodeChild, ...getNodeChildByNodeInfo(item)];
      }
    });
  }
  return listNodeChild;
}

function toggleNodeSelectedParent(nodeId) {
  const nodeParent = $('#tree').treeview('getParent', nodeId);
  if (nodeParent && nodeParent.nodes) {
    $('#tree').treeview('expanded', nodeParent.nodeId);
    $('#tree').treeview(nodeParent.nodes.length === nodeParent.nodes.filter(itemChild => itemChild.state.selected).length
      ? 'selectNode' : 'unselectNode', nodeParent.nodeId);
    toggleNodeSelectedParent(nodeParent.nodeId);
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you edit your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score -1):

I tried the previous answers and it has bugs. I fixed it according the below code

```
                var treeCheck = $('.treeCheck').treeview({
                    data: res,
                    nodeIcon: "fa fa-desktop",
                    expandIcon: 'fa fa-angle-left',
                    collapseIcon: 'fa fa-angle-down',
                    checkedIcon: 'fa fa-check-circle',
                    uncheckedIcon: 'fa fa-circle-o',
                    showBorder: false,
                    showCheckbox: true
                }).on('nodeChecked', function (event, node){
                    
                    var childrenNodes = _getChildren(node);
                    for (i = 0; i < childrenNodes.length; i++) {
                         $('.treeCheck').treeview('checkNode', [ childrenNodes[i], { silent: true } ]);
                    } 
                    
                }).on('nodeUnchecked', function (event, node){
                    var childrenNodes = _getChildren(node);

                    for (i = 0; i < childrenNodes.length; i++) {
                        $('.treeCheck').treeview('uncheckNode', [ childrenNodes[i], { silent: false } ]);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: function _getChildren(node) {
    if (node.nodes === undefined) return [];
    var childrenNodes = node.nodes;
    node.nodes.forEach(function(n) {
        childrenNodes = childrenNodes.concat(_getChildren(n));
    });
    return childrenNodes;
}